# how to hide field during serialization (but not deserialization)

Tags: serialization, jackson, hide, swagger, springfox

In our project (springMVC) Rest API project I wish to only use ONE model for both request and response (to avoid having to add tons of code to copy field from object to object)

I'd like to use Swagger to handle all the doc, but I'm running into a little problem. For example let say I have a model User

```
public class User  {
 private Long id;
 private String username;
 private String password;
}
```

And a simple controller

```
 public void createUser(@RequestBody User user)...
 public User getUser(Long id) ..
```

Now I would like swagger to hide the property password on deserialization but not serialization (so having it display for the Input but the output)
and the opposite for the Id field.

**I have tried using @JsonIgnore coupled with @JsonProperty** but on the swagager-ui it either displays everything or hides everything. I cannot manage to it work.

Could someone indicate me what is the best way of archiving my goal ? Is it possible to use a single model for request and response while using swagger? In case it is not possible to use @JsonIgnore, is there a way to archive this differently ?

Answer (score 2):

Swagger doesn't want you to have different input/output models with the same name.  You should simply create an interface and attach that to the input, and for the output extend that interface or add an implementation with the additional field.  For example, please see here for modeling tips:

https://swaggerhub.com/api/swagger-tutorials/modeling-samples/1.0.0

Your exact use case is one of them.  The solution posted in the above link is here:

```
definitions:
  User:
    description: this is a user that would be passed into the system
    properties:
      username:
        type: string
  UserResponse:
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/User'
      - type: object
        required:
          - id
        properties:
          id:
            type: string
            format: uuid
            readOnly: true
```

where `User` is the input object, and `UserResponse` is the output object, with the additional `id` field.

Comment: I did try to go on the interface route but I didn't manage to have springMVC's '@RequestBody' working with an interface. I mean it DID work for swagger but I cannot call the endpoint because it doesn't know which implementation to use. (I had create a UserRequest interface with getUsername and setUsername and I had User implement it, and i have put the UserRequest in the @RequestBody and User as a response)

Comment: The second problem I had with interface was 'sub object'. Consider I have an "Address" object in the User class. I do not which to deserialise the field address for example inside the Address object

Comment: Can you try with a java class for `User` and `UserResponse` as a subclass?  I would expect springfox to make this work fine.  You might need to open an issue on that repo

Answer (score 1):

Add **@JsonIgnore** with getter of the field and **@JsonProperty** with the setter or with the field . As Due to use of immutable code or final fields sometime setter doesn't work.

example :

```
  public class Student {
   private Float name;
   private String rollnum;
   private String section;
   @JsonProperty
   private Boolean passOrFailed;

   @JsonIgnore
   public Boolean getpassOrFailed {
     return active;
   }
```

}

Remember to use both else else it will lead to removing element in deserialization